# Want To Validate The Index Number Of A Given Array Using If

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

```
 class Palette
 {  
      public static void Main()
      {    
           int array = new int [5];
           if (array[] = 0)
           {
                   Console.WriteLine("It's blue");
           }
           if (array[] = 1)
           {
                   Console.WriteLine("It's Violet");
           }
           if (array[] = 2)
           {
                   Console.WriteLine("It's red");
           }
           if (array[] = 3)
           {
                   Console.WriteLine("It's Black");
           }
           if (array[] = 4)
           {
                   Console.WriteLine("It's green");
           }
           Random ran = new Random();
           int r = ran.Next(array.Length);
           string Token = (array[r]);
           Console.WriteLine(Token);
   }
}
```

---

This is not working. How can i make it work.

Comment: What is that supposed to do? This code makes no sense.

Comment: I understand you're beginner. The code does not make sense as it stands. Tell us what you want to do.

Comment: `array[] = 1` is trying to assign the value of 1 to the entire array. I'm guessing you're looking for something more like `if (array[0] ==1`, but this still won't work since you haven't entered anything into the array so it will be populated with NULLs

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] array = new string[5];
    array[0] = "It's blue";
    array[1] = "It's Violet";
    array[2] = "It's red";
    array[3] = "It's Black";
    array[4] = "It's green";
    Random ran = new Random();
    int r = ran.Next(array.Length);
    string token = array[r];
    Console.WriteLine(token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
if (array[0] == "Blue") {
    Console.WriteLine("It's blue");
}

if (array[1] = "Violet") {
   Console.WriteLine("It's violet");
}
```